# Delete a branch named <U+0096><U+0096>DEV- in Git-for-Windows shell

Tags: windows, git

I renamed a branch to a name copied from Firefox and pasted into the Git-for-Windows shell (MinGW64) and now branch is named `<U+0096><U+0096>DEV-`. Afaik the leading `<U+0096>` represent invisible or non-printable characters which the shell fails to ignore or it's a quite annoying issue in Jira where I copied the branch name from.

I was able to cherry-pick the commit based on the commit hash in `reflog`. Now, I want to get rid of the branch (preferrably on the command line in order to learn some Windows tricks).

Comment: I finally deleted the branch using the `gitg` GUI.

Answer (score 6):

In `bash` you can use C-style escape sequences with this syntax: `$'string'`. So you can delete the branch with

```
> git branch -D $'\x96\x96DEV-'
```

Just in case you don't know the exact bytes you can use this to find out:

```
> git show-ref | sed -n 's#.* refs/heads/##p' | grep -a DEV- | hexdump -C
00000000  96 96 44 45 56 2d 0a                              |..DEV-.|
00000007
```

You have to omitt the trailing `0a` or `0d 0a` though.

Comment: Thanks for you input. On Ubuntu 18.10 the branch is displayed as `<U+0096>`. Meanwhile it's easier to delete to branch from there for me. Any idea?

Comment: The syntax I have shown is `bash` syntax. Therefore it will work in `git-bash` on Windows and plain `bash` on Linux in the same way.

Comment: I agree that it should work, but it doesn't (on Ubuntu 18.10), unfortunately. I tried `git branch -D $'\x96'` for the branch displayed as `<U+0096>` in the output of `git branch -a` (says `error: branch '�' not found.`).

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
git branch -D $'\xC2\x96\xC2\x96DEV-'
```

UTF encoding for character 96 is `0xC296`

Comment: Modified version of this (`git branch -d $'\xC2\x96'`) solved the problem described by @kalle-richter (i.e. there being a branch shown as `<U+0096>`). I encountered it on Git Bash on Windows 10, while trying to paste a branch name. And before I knew, `git branch` spitted out `fatal: A branch named '' already exists`. Thanks.